# Styling empty HTML markup

Tags: css

I have a right sidebar in my design that pulls in testimonials dynamically, if there are any.

The HTML looks like:

```
<h4> dynamic content</h4>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
#testimonials {
    background: #eeeeee; 
    padding: 30px; 
    width: auto; 
    height: auto;
}

#testimonials h4{
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-family: "freight-big-pro";
    font-style: italic; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #666; 
    padding-bottom: 20px; 
    padding-top: 20px;
}

#testimonials h4 strong{
    display: block; 
    font-family:"freight-sans-pro", sans-serif; 
    font-style: normal; 
    font-size: 12px; 
}
```

The issue is that when there is no content in the `<h4>` element, the style is still being picked up and adds a background and a border as specified in the CSS. I am assuming that it's generating the h4. Is there a way to have it be empty if there is not any content?

Update:

I am trying this and it seems to work in jsfiddle, but not in the file:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function(){ if ($("#testimonials").text().length < 65) { $('#testimonials').hide(); } });</script>
```

It counts the HTML inside as text, I think.

Comment: This sounds like something you will need to accomplish with jQuery or javascript.

Comment: Why not have whatever is generating the content also generate the `<h4>` tag? This way there wouldn't be anything to style if no testimonials exist.

Comment: CSS has no way to read, see, or check the length of the content of an element.

Comment: @j08691 There is actually a selector in CSS3 that does let you check if an element is empty. See my answer.

Comment: Something is missing from the markup: there is no element with id `testimonials`, so none of the CSS rules apply. It is not clear what element might be empty and whether it is really empty. E.g., a `div` element containing an `h3` cannot be empty, even if the `h3` is empty.

Comment: @j08691 (that was me who said that). It also isn't tagged with CSS2! So we shall have to wait and see what they are actually looking for.

Comment: yes the h4 is inside a div testimonials, so that will explain why the empty pseudo is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `#testimonials` a `display: none;` property in your CSS; then, just before whatever Javascript code you use to pull in testimonials finishes running, have it check whether it actually retrieved any, and  set `display: block;` on `#testimonials` if so.

Somewhat related: When asking questions on Stack Overflow, it's ideal to post as much information as possible, as for example the code you're using to retrieve testimonials dynamically -- it's mentioned in the question and its behavior affects what you're asking about, which makes it well within scope. If you'll update your question with your testimonial-retrieving code, I'll update my answer to show a specific solution.

Comment: thanks, gotcha! I also tried this but not working<script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function(){
   if ($("#testimonials").text().length > 0) {
     $('#testimonials').css( "display", "block" );
   }                                           
 });</script>

Comment: @Deedub Please, for the love of all that's holy, edit your question to contain the Javascript code you use to retrieve testimonials. With that visible, I can edit a specific solution into my answer in a matter of minutes, and we can all go on with our lives. :)

Comment: lol ok Aaron, I just tried it. So I was replying to where it was relevant.

Comment: also, I don't use js to retrieve the data.

Comment: I know this part works in js fiddle but for whatever reason, it does not work in my code. The solution is correct.

Comment: @Deedub Well, as long as it's working for you, that's what I'm after. Glad to have helped out.

Comment: yeh, thanks to everyone. I will need to be better about posting question.. was rushing it :) The solution works in js fiddle very nicely, but for some reason it won't work in my html, so am not sure why.. but that's on me.

Comment: Make sure you are referencing jquery.  Firebug will show you why it isn't working.

Answer (score 2):

### Update

Here is another <kbd>[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p337/47FQw/)</kbd>, but this also probably won't work for the OP as it uses jQuery.

#### jQuery

```
//onload:
checkStyle();   

//checks if the h4 is empty, and hides the whole div if so.
function checkStyle ()
{
    if ($('#testimonials h4').is(':empty')) 
        $('#testimonials').hide();
    else 
        $('#testimonials').show();    
}
```

---

**This does not necessarily work for what the asker is looking for, but could be beneficial for future readers. It is for not styling the h4, not the parent div as op wants.**

Assuming you are ok with CSS3, and the `<h4>` is literally empty, you can  modify your CSS to use the [`:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anot) and [`:empty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3aempty) selectors.

#### CSS

```
#testimonials h4:not(:empty) {
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-family:"freight-big-pro";
    font-style: italic;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
#testimonials h4:not(:empty) strong {
    display: block;
    font-family:"freight-sans-pro", sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

Here is a <kbd>[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p337/CD4nT/)</kbd>. You can add content to the h4 to see how it works.

Alternatively, you could even do the opposite, and have a `display:none;` for empty `<h4>`s:

```
#testimonials h4:empty{
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: the empty does not work for some reason, and I think it's as mentioned above, since the div has an h4 inside of it, then there is not considered empty?

Comment: The CSS in this answer will only work if there is nothing, including whitespace, within the `<h4>`. Likewise, if you try to style `div:empty`, then you cannot have an `h4` within the `div` or else the CSS will not be applied to the `div`.

Comment: If there is a child element inside of the div, then it is not empty. I was thinking you just wanted the <h4> to not be styled, rather than the whole div.

Comment: yeah basically,if there no CONTENT I want none of the styles to apply.. so it's looking like js is my option?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately so. Kinda messy, but CSS only cascades down, not up. Ideally, you could just not put in the h4 unless you are using it.

Comment: @Deedub I updated my answer with a jquery solution, but it appears you are using just JS. It may be helpful for future readers though, so I will leave it.

Comment: In jQuery, rather than `if (condition) el.show() else el.hide()` you can use the Boolean-arg version of toggle: `el.toggle(condition)`

Comment: @StephenP thanks for the tip. I will remember that for the future.

Answer (score 1):

Do a display:none on your css initially when there is no content.
Use javascript or jquery to show content. Styling will be applied when the content gets displayed.

Initially when there is no content:
`#testimonials {
    background: #eeeeee; padding: 30px; width: auto; height: auto;
    display :none;
}`

When content gets generated dynamically use:
`$("#testimonials").show();`

Comment: @Deedub I'm assuming this means no jQuery? Only pure JS, right?

Comment: I was going with jquery.. doesn't have to be pure js.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like alot of front side work when it isn't needed.  If you are able to output content into the h4, then you are able to output and additional tag.

```
<section id="testimonials"></section>
```

Server Side pushes out:

```
<h4>all my content</h4>
```

Then your CSS will work without any work from js.

Most likely you have one  for each testimonial?

Comment: yeah, ideally, I would like to output all code, but I can't I have to add the html first.. so there will be pages with empty tags.

Comment: You have to add ALL the html?  You can't just leave an empty <section> for testimonials and then add the <h4> + content?  There must be some dom structure to the testimonial itself being rendered.

Comment: not in this case, yea that would be ideal and have done similiar using xslt, but in this case, it's basically a shortcode in a widget, wordpress. I could hard code something into the loop but that's a question for the wordpress section and it's not helpful